# Two functions involving recursive sum and dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

I'm doing an assignment. These are the instructions, and the docstring they provide:

> You will write two functions in this challenge. First write a function
>   called `rec_dig_sum` that takes in an integer and returns the recursive
>   digit sum of that number.
>
> Example of recursive digit sums: 101 => 1+0+1 = 2.
>
> Then use that function within another function called
>   `distr_of_rec_digit_sums`, that returns a dictionary where the keys are
>   recursive digit sums, and the values are the counts of those digit
>   sums occurring between a low and high (inclusive) range of input
>   numbers. Assume low and high are positive integers where high is
>   greater than low, and neither low nor high are negative. Your function
>   should return a dictionary, not just print it.
>
> ```
> def rec_dig_sum(n):
>     '''
>     Returns the recursive digit sum of an integer.
>
>     Parameter
>     ---------
>     n: int
>
>     Returns
>     -------
>     rec_dig_sum: int
>        the recursive digit sum of the input n
>     '''
>
> def distr_of_rec_digit_sums(low=0, high=1500):
>     '''
>     Returns a dictionary representing the counts
>         of recursive digit sums within a given range.
>
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     low: int
>         an integer, 0 or positive, representing
>         the lowest value in the range of integers
>         for which finding the recursive digit sum
>     high: int
>         a positive integer greater than low, the
>         inclusive upper bound for which finding
>         the recursive digit sum
>
>     Returns
>     -------
>     dict_of_rec_dig_sums: {int:int}
>         returns a dictionary where the keys are
>         the recursive digit sums and the values
>         are the counts of those digit sums occurring
>     '''
> ```

This is the code I have attempted:

```
def rec_dig_sum(n):
  convert_to_int = [int(i) for i in lst]
  total = sum(convert_to_int)
  return total

def distr_of_rec_digit_sums(low=0, high=1500):
  if length >= 0 and length <= 1500 :
    d1 = {rec_dig_sum(n) : length}
  return d1

lst = list(str(n))
total = 0
length = len(lst)

print(distr_of_rec_digit_sums(5987))
```

I am not sure why inputting the argument at the end of the function causes an error, as the first function should run using the same argument.

Am I approaching this correctly? Is there a way to make this better?

Comment: Which argument at the end of which function do you mean? What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

First, your function is passed an argument, `n`, which is the integer whose digits are to be added together but you completely ignore this value and instead compute the sum using the value `lst`. The initialization of `lst` is performing half the work required to produce the result. All of the work necessary for producing the result should be in function `rec_dig_sum`, which should use the value `n` passed to it and nothing else. Using the approach you have taken, which is satisfactory, we then have:

```
def rec_dig_sum(n):
    convert_to_int = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
    total = sum(convert_to_int)
    return total
```

Second, your statement `lst = list(str(n))` will generate an error because `n` is only defined as a function argument to `rec_dig_sum` and is therefore not in scope.

Third, my interpretation of your exercise is that function `distr_of_rec_digit_sums` will be passed two values, `low` and `high`, and using those values you should generate all the integers in the range `low, low + 1 ... high` and for each one call function `rec_dig_sum`. These repeated calls to `rec_dig_sum` will result in returning a finite number of distinct values (this number being at least 1 and at most `high - low + 1`). You are for each distinct value count how many times that value occurred and create a dictionary where each key is a distinct value returned by `rec_dig_sum` and the value is the count of times that value was returned. For example, calling `rec_dig_sum` with arguments `12` and `21` will both result in the value `2` returned. So, if the function `distr_of_rec_digit_sums` is called with `low=12` and `high=21`, then one of the dictionary keys will be `2` with a value of 2 (the count). You are then to return that dictionary. Now that I have hopefully explained this better, I will leave it to you make an improved attempt. If you have problems with this, pose it as a separate question.